# How to inject variables into u-boot build at build time

Tags: c, makefile, preprocessor, u-boot

I am a u-boot newbie.

I want to be able to make u-boot with a different build option at build time.  E.g. I might have a `build.sh` like this:

```
source /path/to/target-toolchain

make distclean
make MyHardware_defconfig
make V=1
```

or even better:

```
make distclean
make MyHardware_defconfig
make CONFIG_ENABLE_CONSOLE=1 V=1
```

In MyHardware.c:

```
#if !defined CONFIG_ENABLE_CONSOLE
  #error CONFIG_ENABLE_CONSOLE not defined!!!!!
#endif
```

I tried adding CONFIG_ENABLE_CONSOLE=1 to MyHardware_defconfig but when build get error line

I also tried make CONFIG_ENABLE_CONSOLE=1 V=1 but also same as above error.

How can I setup my project so I can build for both console enabled and disabled?  Without having to hard code in the u-boot source code.

Comment: "*In MyHardware.c: ...*" -- You seem to have a common misconception: the `CONFIG_` symbols in the defconfig or **.config** files are not directly available to source code during the preprocesing stage of compilation. The **make** script has to translate the **.config** file into the **autoconf.h** file that will always be included for preprocessing.

Comment: "*How to inject variables ...*" -- One method of passing information from the shell (aka command line) to build process is through various environment variables. In particular the (exported) environment variables CPPFLAGS or CFLAGS (containing `-Dmacro_expr`) can be used to inject a macro during preprocessing or compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uboot makefile has:

```
# Add user supplied CPPFLAGS, AFLAGS and CFLAGS as the last assignments
KBUILD_CPPFLAGS += $(KCPPFLAGS)
KBUILD_AFLAGS += $(KAFLAGS)
KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(KCFLAGS)
```

So this works from a build script:

```
export KCPPFLAGS+=" -DCONFIG_ENABLE_CONSOLE"
```

then run make

or :

```
make KCPPFLAGS+=" -DCONFIG_ENABLE_CONSOLE"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
make MyHardware_defconfig
```

creates file *.config*. The usual way to edit it is calling

```
make menuconfig
```

If you want to modify *.config* in a script, you could use *sed*.

The configuration options are defined in files called *Kconfig*. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.18/kbuild/kconfig-language.html describes the syntax of *Kconfig* files.

Comment: "*If you want to modify .config in a script ...*" -- Bad advice (esp to a newbie) that deserves a downvote.